# Custom metabox field not show HTML

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

A have a meta box

```
    'portfolio_single_add_field3' => array(
                'title' => esc_html__( 'Additional Field 3', 'bonza' ),
                'description' => '',
                'id' => $prefix . 'portfolio_single_add_field3',
                'type' => 'text',
            ),

<?php if( isset( $bonza_portfolio_single_add_field_title3 ) && $bonza_portfolio_single_add_field_title3 != '' ) { ?>
                                    <div class="portfolio_single_det">
                                        <p><strong><?php echo esc_attr( $bonza_portfolio_single_add_field_title3 ); ?></strong>
                                        <span class="portfolio-add_field">
                                            <?php echo esc_attr( $bonza_portfolio_single_add_field3 ); ?>
                                        </span></p>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
```

And on the portfolio page I get < p > < strong > etc...

Please help

Comment: did you fix the problem?

Comment: no fix the problem...